# How to best handle shared services using docker-compose for local development in microservice architecture?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

Trying to set up an effective pattern that allows communication between all of my services and allows for local development on multiple services simultaneously. I am currently setting up local development for my application using docker compose. The basic idea of my `docker-compose.yml` looks something like this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web: 
    <web_config>
  worker:
    <worker_config>
  service-a:
```

I'm questioning how to handle `service-a`.

`service-a` is required by any local applications I am running. So if I am running this application and another at the same time, they will both need to communicate with `service-a`.

Should `service-a` be running in its own compose instance? If so, are `networks` the best way for all my apps to communicate with `service-a`? From my understanding, this used to be the job of `links`, but `networks` are now preferred. I have already tried running with `network_mode` host, but am running into issues, as I am using Docker for Mac.

I've seen a lot of opinions and solutions out there, but I'm honestly unsure which of these approaches is best. Some of the solutions I've seen include:

- creating a shared `network` for all my services and run them separately in their own docker composes
- using `network_mode: 'host'` and run everything on my host (Sadly I couldn't get this working)
- running a separate compose of all my shared services that all other services depend on

Let me know if you've run into this and have any advice to share, thanks!

Comment: How are you configuring service-a in your docker-compose.yml? Could you provide those details?

Comment: I didn't provide that config because I'm not trying to set anything specific up at this point. Looking for ideas on the `how` to best approach this problem. I just included the snippet of the docker-compose to illustrate the dependency.

Comment: Ok, then when you say `I originally tried to just have service-a running from this app's docker-compose, but I ran another application simultaneously and couldn't communicate with service-a from that application.` you were trying to run the other application in another docker-compose?

Comment: Just updated my post and removed that. Thanks for pointing that out. Failed to clearly articulate my point that I started trying that as an approach, but it didn't feel right. And since by default, each compose creates a separate network (to my understanding, or technically its a `bridge` network), that lead me to thinking that using a shared `network` may be the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each docker-compose stands up its own network for the services it manages. As you proposed, using a shared bridge network would be the easiest way to ensure each different stack of services in separate docker-compose.yml would be able to connect to one another.

[You can tell docker-compose to look for and use a pre-existing network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks). You can create this network with `docker network create` or maybe specify it in your service-a docker-compose.yml as a custom network with a static name:

service-a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-a:
    ...

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Then use that network in your other docker-compose.yml files. You need to specify the network at the *top level* of the docker-compose.yml and then you can tell each service to use it:

some other docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    ...
  networks:
    - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external:
      name: mynetwork
```

I only suggest the second option since you said any other app would need service-a running anyway.

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is that all services added to `mynetwork` will be able to communicate with each other. I don't like this idea as it dilutes the idea of seperating applications as well as there might arise a [hostname conflict](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases).

Comment: See [this bit about custom networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks). You could make a service-a network for each service that connects to service-a if separation is vital to your stack.